# Masking a C++ Vector with an array of uchar

Tags: c++, stl

I have an uchar array called mask. It contains either 0 or 1.

```
uchar mask
```

I have a STL vector

```
vector<MyClass> vec
```

Size of mask and vec are the same.

What is the best way to form a sub-vector from vec which contains the original contents at the places where the mask was 1

Comment: What do you expect in places where the mask is `0`?

Answer (score 1):

```
vector<MyClass> vec2;
vec2.resize(vec.size());
for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i) {
    if (mask[i])
        vec2[i] = vec[i];
}
```

As simple as it can be.  `vec2` will contain default constructed objects of your class in positions where the mask was `0`, so you'll need some way to tell them apart.

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach I like to "filter out" parts of a vector inplace is the readptr-writeptr idiom:

```
int wp = 0;
for (int rp=0,n=v.size(); rp<n; rp++) {
    if (<condition>) {
        v[wp++] = v[rp];
    }
}
v.resize(wp);
```

or even using:

```
if (wp != rp) v[wp] = v[rp];
wp++;
```

if elements are "heavy" and don't detect self-assignment.

If the destination is a different vector then an explicit loop:

```
for (int rp=0,n=src.size(); rp<n; rp++) {
    if (<condition>) {
        dest.push_back(src[rp]);
    }
}
```

is in my opinion better than using `copy_if` and `back_inserter` stuff (that also don't make the index available to use in the `condition` part).

Even in C++11 that allows you to use a lambda to specify the test inplace with

```
std::copy_if(src.begin(), src.end(),
             [](const X& x) { return <condition>; },
             std::back_inserter(dest));
```

This `<algorithm>`-based code is uglier to read (at least for my eyes), not shorter, takes much longer to compile, the code will not be better and the compiler will generate three screenfuls of nonsense babbling instead of a reasonable error message if you make a typo anywhere in it.

with C++11 the version

```
for (auto& x : src) if (condition) dst.push_back(x);
```

is anyway much better.

Comment: Given the fact that he's using a mask, I expect that the inidices need to be maintained.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want the default content where mask is 1, then it is simple like this:

```
vector<MyClass> sub;
for (size_t i = 0; i < mask.size(); ++i){
    if (mask[i]) sub.push_back(vec[i]);
}
```

Otherwise, you can use transform with lambda if your compiler supports c++0x.

```
vector<MyClass> sub;
std::transform(mask.begin(), mask.end(), vec.begin(), back_inserter(sub), 
    [](const uchar m, const MyClass &c){
        return m ? c : MyClass();
});
```

Comment: An advantage of using `transform` compared to using `operator[]` is that it still work if your contents or mask is list.